# Avfoundation mix audios with different volumes doesn't not work

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I'd like to merge a video(a mp4 file) and an audio(a mp3 file) by AVAssetExportSession with different volumes. E.g, the audio's volume from the video might be 1 and the other audio's volume might be 0.5 as background music. However, it seems like `[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolume]` or `[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume]` don't work. The music's volume in output file seems like not getting lower at all.

The code is shown as following

```
AVMutableComposition *mixComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc] init];
// add a video track
AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[videoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
NSMutableArray *audioMixParams = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSError *error;

if (musicPath && mVolume > 0) {
    // add a music track
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

    AVURLAsset *musicAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:musicPath] options:nil];
    if ([[musicAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] <= 0) {
        [self.logger error:@"music file error : ", musicPath];
        handler(NO);
        return;
    }
    AVAssetTrack *musicAudioTrack = [[musicAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *musicParam = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    musicParam.trackID = musicAudioTrack.trackID;
    [self.logger debug:@"merge video and music : set music source volume -> %f", mVolume];
    // set music's volume
    [musicParam setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:mVolume toEndVolume:mVolume timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)];
    // add param to mix
    [audioMixParams addObject:musicParam];

    [audioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:musicAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
    if (error) {
        [self.logger error:@"Error when insert audio track of music file : %@", error.description];
    }
}

if ([[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count] && vVolume > 0) {
    // add video sound track
    AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
    AVAssetTrack * sourceAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *videoParam = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
    videoParam.trackID = sourceAudioTrack.trackID;
    [self.logger debug:@"merge video and music : set video source volume -> %f", vVolume];
    // set video's audio volume
    [videoParam setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:vVolume toEndVolume:vVolume timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration)];
    // add param to mix
    [audioMixParams addObject:videoParam];

    [videoAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:sourceAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:&error];
    if (error) {
        [self.logger error:@"Error when insert audio track of video file : %@", error.description];
    }
}

// merge
audioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithArray:audioMixParams];

AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
exporter.outputURL= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
exporter.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
exporter.audioMix = audioMix;
exporter.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration);
[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
}];
```

Could anyone help? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried - setVolume:atTime: ? (make sure to set CMTime correctly)

Comment: yes, i used `setVolume:0.5 atTime:CMTimeZero` at first, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes, I think so... It was long long ago...I don't quite remember, sorry :-(

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804888/setting-multiple-volumes-to-each-video-tracks-using-audiomixinputparameters-avfo

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54804888/setting-multiple-volumes-to-each-video-tracks-using-audiomixinputparameters-avfo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. The AudioMixInputParameters must take the track ID of the CompositionTrack, not of the AVAssetTrack